# Dynamically Creating Lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am  trying to create a list from the response to an AJAX call that I invoke.

Format 1:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "BirthdayInvitations.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function ParseXml(xml) {
        $("div#menu").append('<ul "data-role="listview"> ');
        var ul = $("div#menu  > ul");
        $(xml).find("event").each(function() {
            $(ul).append('<li><a href="' + "hai" + '">' + this.textContent+ '</a></li>'); 
        });
        $('ul').listview('refresh');
    }
});
```

Format 2:

I had even tried with the below format as well.

```
$('ul').append($('<li/>', {    //here appendin `<li>`
    'data-role':"listview"
}).append($('<a/>', {    //here appending `<a>` into `<li>`
    'href': 'test.html',
    'data-transition': 'slide',
    'text': '$(this).textContent'
})));
```

The result of Format 1 is the plain list of anchor tags.

Please help me in getting the solution, I need a list view created dynamically.

Format 2: doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've amended your first example. The issue of plain `LI` tags being appended sounds like the `this.textContent` call to your XML data isn't finding anything, is that the correct tag/attribute name?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "BirthdayInvitations.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        var $ul = $("<ul></ul>").data("role", "listview");
        $(xml).find("event").each(function() {
            $ul.append('<li><a href="' + "hai" + '">' + this.textContent + '</a></li>'); 
        });
        $ul.appendTo("DIV#menu");
        $ul.listview('refresh');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Rory thanks for the reply. but the result is the same after applying ur snippet. its showing me the plain list of links.its not apllying the listview. this is the snippet. function init()
{
    type: "GET",
$.ajax({
 url: "BirthdayInvitations.xml",
 dataType: "xml",
 success: function ParseXml(xml)
 {
  var $ul = $("<ul></ul>").data("role", "listview");    
     $(xml).find("event").each(function() {  
  $ul.append('<li><a href="' + "hai" + '">' + this.textContent + '</a></li>');
  }); 
  $ul.appendTo("DIV#menu"); 
  $ul.listview('refresh'); 
  }}); 
      
     }

Comment: Hai can any one post the snippet that satisfies my requirment.

Comment: Hi rory, I am getting the following exception when i debug through firebug. and the result is showing all the data like normal list uncaught exception: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you'd need to call $ul.listview('create') the first time since the listview is not yet created - that 'refresh' can only be called in successive calls..